# Google Batch Job Notifications Not Arriving at Pub/Sub Topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been running an experiment where the goal is to run a Google batch job and when it successfully completes its tasks it sends a notification to a Pub/Sub topic. However, despite setting the job to send notifications the messages do not arrive at the Pub/Sub topic. No error message is displayed.

**Expected result**

I expect that when running a batch job it will run its tasks successfully and when it finishes and changes its status to success it will send a notification to a Pub/Sub topic. This notification published by the batch job would have to reach a subscription associated with the Pub/Sub topic in question and be viewed.

**Experiment performed**

1. Create and define a batch job using a *config.json* file. In this example, the batch job runs 3 tasks. Each task consists of printing a string. In addition, I specify a notification in the *notifications* attribute (explained in detail in the following steps). I utilized a custom service account [1, 2] with these roles:* `Batch agent reporter, Batch job editor, Compute Storage Admin, Google Batch service agent, Logs Writer, and Pub/Sub Publisher.`*

Here, the content of the *config.json:*

```
{
    "taskGroups": [
        {
            "taskSpec": {
                "runnables": [
                    {
                        "script": {
                            "text": "echo Hello ${VARIABLE_NAME}! This is task ${BATCH_TASK_INDEX}. This job has a total of ${BATCH_TASK_COUNT} tasks."
                        },
                        "environment": {
                            "variables": {
                                "VARIABLE_NAME": "WORLD"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "computeResource": {
                    "cpuMilli": 2000,
                    "memoryMib": 16
                },
                "maxRetryCount": 0,
                "maxRunDuration": "7200s"
            },
            "taskCount": 3,
            "parallelism": 1
        }
    ],
    "allocationPolicy": {
        "serviceAccount": {
            "email": "my-custom-service-account@my-gcp-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        },
        "instances": [
            {
                "policy": {
                    "machineType": "e2-standard-4"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "logsPolicy": {
        "destination": "CLOUD_LOGGING"
    },
    "notifications": [
            {
                "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic",
                "message": {
                        "type": "JOB_STATE_CHANGED",
                        "newJobState": "SUCCEEDED",
                        "newTaskState": "STATE_UNSPECIFIED"
                }
            }
      ]
}
```

I configured the batch job to send notifications to a Pub/Sub topic named *my-topic* when the job status changes to success. According to the batch job configuration [3], notifications are specified in the *notifications* attribute. As per the JSON structure [4] for batch job notifications, it should follow this format:

```
{
  "pubsubTopic": string,
  "message": {
    "type": enum (Type),
    "newJobState": enum (State),
    "newTaskState": enum (State)
  }
}
```

where *Type* is one of the enums [TYPE_UNSPECIFIED, JOB_STATE_CHANGED, TASK_STATE_CHANGED], and *State* is one of the enums ["STATE_UNSPECIFIED", "QUEUED", "SCHEDULED", "RUNNING", "SUCCEEDED", "FAILED", "DELETION_IN_PROGRESS"].

Precisely, the notification I configured was:

```
{
  "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic",
  "message": {
    "type": "JOB_STATE_CHANGED",
    "newJobState": "SUCCEEDED",
    "newTaskState": "STATE_UNSPECIFIED"
  }
}
```

2. In Cloud Pub/Sub console, I created a Pub/Sub topic [5] named *my-topic* (*projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic*) and associated it with an AVRO schema [6] named *noti-avro-schema* (*projects/my-gcp-project/schemas/noti-avro-schema*) with the message encoding type set to JSON. I designed the following AVRO schema to represent the JSON structure of the Google Batch notification [4]:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "message",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "type", "type": {
      "type": "enum",
      "name": "Type",
      "symbols": ["TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "JOB_STATE_CHANGED", "TASK_STATE_CHANGED"]
    }},
    {"name": "newJobState", "type": {
      "type": "enum",
      "name": "State",
      "symbols": ["STATE_UNSPECIFIED", "QUEUED", "SCHEDULED", "RUNNING", "SUCCEEDED", "FAILED", "DELETION_IN_PROGRESS"]
    }},
    {"name": "newTaskState", "type": "State"}
  ]
}
```

4. Created a subscription to *my-topic* Pub/Sub topic: *projects/my-gcp-project/subscriptions/my-topic-sub.*

5. Executed a batch job named *job-test* the GCP project *my-gcp-project* using *gcloud* command:

```
gcloud batch jobs submit job-test --location us-central1 --config config.json
```

6. Wait for the batch job to finish successfully and check the subscription to see if the notification has arrived. I pulled the message from the GCP Pub/Sub console.

**Result obtained**

The notification published in the Pub/Sub topic by the batch job is not visible because there is no notification in the subscription. No error alerts are seen...

***I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying the cause of this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!***

**References**

[1] https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started#project-prerequisites [2]https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job-custom-service-account#create-job-service-account [3] https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#resource:-job [4]https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#jobnotification

[5] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/create?hl=en

[6] https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-create-topic-with-schema?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for trying Google Batch.

For the job notification field, if none message attributes are defined, no message will be sent by default.

If there is attribute(s), one message can only have attributes for *job* or *task*, for example:

> job level: type JOB_STATE_CHANGED and/or a specified new_job_state; or

> task level: type TASK_STATE_CHANGED and/or a specified new_task_state.

To achieve "I configured the batch job to send notifications to a Pub/Sub topic named my-topic when the job status changes to success.", you can go with:

```
"notifications": [
  {
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic",
    "message": {
      "type": "JOB_STATE_CHANGED",
      "newJobState": "SUCCEEDED"
    }
  }
]
```

If you want both JOB_STATE_CHANGED for job succeeded and TASK_STATE_CHANGED for all task state changes, you can go with

```
"notifications": [
  {
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic",
    "message": {
      "type": "JOB_STATE_CHANGED",
      "newJobState": "SUCCEEDED"
    }
  },
  {
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/my-gcp-project/topics/my-topic",
    "message": {
      # If only type TASK_STATE_CHANGED is specified, then all kinds of task state change messages will be sent.
      "type": "TASK_STATE_CHANGED",
    }
  }
]
```

Hope this helps. Please let us know if you have any further questions. :-)

Comment: Hi @Wen. I hope you are well. Thank you so much for your reply. I really appreciate it. I tried placing the necessary attributes in the "message" attribute of the notification. Also, I changed the AVRO schema associated to the Pub/Sub topic by removing the "newtaskState" attribute from the AVRO schema I specified in the post. Consequently, when I run the batch job again with this new configuration I can see that a message in the Pub/Sub topic and subscription is detected through the metrics. However, if I do a PULL on the subscription I can't visualise the message. Any idea how to see it?

Comment: Do you think the AVRO notification is correctly mapped? I think maybe there is some problem there...

Comment: Hi Agus, glad to know there is a message shows up. I am not very familiar with AVRO. But if you created a pull pubsub subscription: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription and pull the message, you can check the message body on Google Cloud->PubSub->Subscriptions->Your Subscription->Message Body tab to verify it is arrived and has the right content you want. Then you can modify the AVRO format to parse it accordingly. Please let me know if it works for you. Thanks!